# Remove days based on number of hours missing

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have some air pollution data measured by hours.

| Datetime | PM2.5 | Station.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | NA | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 02:00:00 | 15 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 03:00:00 | NA | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 04:00:00 | 7 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 05:00:00 | 20 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 06:00:00 | 30 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | NA | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | 17 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 02:00:00 | 21 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 03:00:00 | 55 | 2 |

I have a very large number of data collected from many stations. Using R, what is **the most efficient** way to remove a day when it has **1.** A total of 18 hours of missing data AND **2.** 8 hours continuous missing data.

PS. The original data can be either **NAs have already been removed** OR **NAs are inserted**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **"most efficient"** way will almost certainly use `data.table`. Something like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(your_data)
your_data[, date := as.IDate(Datetime)][,
  if(
    !(sum(is.na(PM2.5)) >= 18 & 
    with(rle(is.na(PM2.5)), max(lengths[values])) >= 8
  )) .SD,
  by = .(date, station.id)
]
#          date            Datetime PM2.5
# 1: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 00:00:00    10
# 2: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 01:00:00    NA
# 3: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 02:00:00    15
# 4: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 03:00:00    NA
# 5: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 04:00:00     7
# 6: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 05:00:00    20
# 7: 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 06:00:00    30
```

Using this sample data:

```
your_data = fread(text = 'Datetime  PM2.5
2020-01-01 00:00:00 10
2020-01-01 01:00:00 NA
2020-01-01 02:00:00 15
2020-01-01 03:00:00 NA
2020-01-01 04:00:00 7
2020-01-01 05:00:00 20
2020-01-01 06:00:00 30')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry that I forgot to include anther column of station id.

Comment: Added `station.id` to the `by` argument. Since the output exactly matches the input for the sample data provided, I'm not going to bother re-importing and running it.

Comment: I have received a warning of ```In max(lengths[values]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf```. Does it mean that all is missing or no missing? Thanks

Comment: That means all are missing.